# Error with detecting res/xml and preference activity

Tags: android, xml, preference

I am trying to add a Preference activity in my andorid App, but my eclipse is not recognizing the res/xml folder and addPreferenceFromResources() method is showing as deprecated. So Please help how I can proceed further further. BTW I am reading the Hello Android by Ed Burnette. This thing is mention in Chapter 3 page 54. Please help me guys.

Regards
Simran Preet Singh

Comment: What exactly does eclipse complain about for the res/xml folder? And it's fine to use the deprecated methods for PreferenceActivity, the only reason they're deprecated is because Android wants us to use fragments now.

Comment: when I write addPreferenceFromResources(R.xml.settings) it does not recogonise it..

Comment: Try to backup the file, delete it, and let eclipse auto-generate it. Then override the new create file and re-build the project.

Comment: @Alfasin --> Eclipse is not recognizing the res/xml folder. And I have already tried that 4-5 times. Please any other solution. I am using Ubuntu 12.10 OS.

Comment: Then create a new project (from existing source files)

Comment: :-( okey I try that now ..

Answer (score 1):

Clean and build the project. Replace PreferenceActivity by using PreferenceFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are importing the following in your header statements:

import android.R;

If you are , delete it and see if you can pick up xml/prefs.